# Tabpage Resizing

Tags: c#, winforms

A disclaimer first! This might be a very fundamental question, but I have started learning Winforms Application Development on my own (.net 3.5,C#), and I have this resizing question.

I am developing a small Winforms application that has a standard tab control (along with many other controls) placed in the form. (It has 5 TabPages)
The AutoScroll property for the TabPage has been set to “True”. On reading up what I got to understand is that this will enable the scrollbars to show up at run time while resizing. i.e if the height of the form is reduced it will cause the vertical scrollbar to show up within the TabPage.

While the application is running, what I noticed is that if I reduce the height of the form using the little double headed arrow, the scroll bar does not stay on top, i.e if I adjust the height from below, the bottom end of the scrollbar is no longer there. More precisely I am just looking for a way to keep both ends of the scrollbar on top within a TabPage when the form containing the Tab control is resized.

Comment: No repro.  This needs a screenshot and a small repro project posted to a file sharing service or paste bin.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the problem is that the tabbed control will show scrollbars and may well autosize, but you haven't told the form what to do.

You might want to look at the 'Dock' property of controls, which causes a control to fill a specific area of the form (or other parent control), no matter what it is resized to.

Comment: Dock Property of the Tab control is set to fill